# PHP codesniffer scan whole directory not working

Tags: php

I want to scan entire project using PHPCS (codesniffer) , but problem here is when i am trying to scan it phpcs in current directory so it scans only php files not sub directories.
Any help would be appreciated. I've tried

```
phpcs --report-file=/path/file/  subdirectories1 subdirectories2 ...
```

But again it scans only php files.

Comment: Can't reproduce that.

Comment: But problem is it scans php files only in current directory

Comment: It should work recursively. Which version are you using?

Comment: Try `phpcs --report-file=/path/file/ /full/path/to/project/not/subdirectories`

Comment: PHP_CodeSniffer version 1.5.3 (stable) by Squiz (http://www.squiz.net)

Comment: @LozCheroneツ But i'm in project directory already.

Comment: @WitWikky Did you find the solution for this problem? I am facing same issue